# Traveling outside of Romania with just residency card "slip" from immigration

Tags: romania

my wife applied for a work visa in Romania, and is now in the final stage of waiting for the residence card to be picked up. She received a "slip" or note from the immigration office telling her to pick it up this week. We went, but they told us it is not ready yet.

The problem is, we already had a trip scheduled outside of Romania next week. Has anyone traveled outside of Romania and returned with just the passport and the "slip" from the immigration showing that her card is being prepared?

Comment: Is the type D visa on which you entered still valid?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, she entered Romania on a 90 day tourist visa. She is a Japanese national. She was able to apply for the work visa within those 90 days. But those 90 days of the tourist visa has passed already, and we are now just waiting for the card, so technically the tourist visa is up already.